# Windows disk imaging software which can save drivers and boot sector separately during backup?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, restore, windows-backup, imaging

I tried cloning an SSD from one laptop to a similar laptop. The laptop is running Windows 7 Enterprise. The second laptop has a larger and different model SSD. Both laptops have only a single drive, not USB devices attached. After the restore, the laptop doesn't boot.

I get an error "...Status: 0xc000000f Info: The best selection failed because a required device is inaccessible".

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  Status: 0xc000000f

  Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.
```

I used True Image 2014 and the Windows built-in system imaging option and they both gave the same error after restoring. I did the Windows repair option and it said it couldn't fix the problem. I used bootsect.exe to write the MBR. Used bcdedit.exe and it doesn't show any 'unknown' devices. I am not sure why Windows laptop is not booting properly.

This is what I want to try doing. Install Windows 7 from scratch. Then install a disk imaging software that has the capability to save the MBR and drivers and anything that is specific to the SSD. Then I want to restore the image to the SSD where it loads the stuff saved earlier during the backup. Yes it will write and wipe the Windows 7 installation. I am thinking the restore needs some help in installing stuff which make Windows work with this specific SSD. The SSD installation disk doesn't have any drives. It's a Samsung EVO drive.

Any ideas if there's such imaging software or if someone has a better idea? I am going to try Paragon Disk Manager, Norton Ghost and DiskProtect and see if I have better success with these.

Comment: Did you get the regular Acronis or did you get the universal driver tool also?

Comment: Do you mean Universal Restore? I don't see anything about universal driver tool on their site. I used universal restore. At the end of the restore there's an option to load drivers. I didn't have a cd ready.

Comment: In the 2014 flavor it is called 2014 Premium.

Comment: I have 2014 Premium. Which tool are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the last stage, true Image universal restore was asking for a driver for \ven_8086&dev_1E03&SUBSYS_176B103C&REV_04. It didn't make sense for me so I told it to ignore it. It turns out it's the driver for the SATA AHCI Controller and without it Windows can't boot. I downloaded the driver from the laptop's manufacturer web site and when that prompt came back, it loaded the driver and the system booted. (Note: I installed a fresh copy of Windows on the second laptop and used a tool DoubleDriver to copy all the drivers to the USB drive for Universal Restore to use for the TI restore, for some reason it didn't use the AHCI driver so I got the one from the website.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, similar is not the same.  You need to inject all the drivers for the other laptop into the source laptop.  Especially, the chipset and SATA/AHCI drivers.

create a **c:\drivers** folder
copy the extract drivers into said folder

**pnputil.exe -a c:\drivers\*.inf**          -> Add all packages in c:\drivers\

When the process is complete you may delete **c:\drivers** if you want to save space.
Clone the source to the destination with any software you want.

Comment: Copy what extract drivers? Am I copying some inf files manually into the drivers folder? pnputil.exe -a c:\drivers\*.inf gives an error ".. invalid INF passed as parameter"

Comment: Download the chipset and SATA drivers and extract them into c:\drivers   Then run the command.